# Footer for every column in parallel column page layout

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, parcolumns

I have a page layout with multiple parallel columns. How can I add a footer for each column on every page?

Currently I'm using `parcolumns` to add two parallel columns in a `fancyhdr` footer.

However, this prints the footer multiple times.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot{
        \begin{parcolumns}{2}
          \colchunk{foo}
          \colchunk{bar}
        \end{parcolumns}
        }
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\begin{parcolumns}{2}
  \colchunk{
    \blindtext
  }
  \colchunk{
    \blindtext
  }
\end{parcolumns}

\end{document}
```

[image: page with two equal columns containing lorem ipsum placeholder text, in the top right corner the page number "1", at the bottom under the left column the footer "foo" three times and under the right column the text "bar" three times with distributed spacing]

Comment: aren't `\rfoot , \lfoot and \cfoot` sufficient? refer to page 46 of `fancyhdr` manual https://ctan.crest.fr/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf

Comment: Try  just  `\fancyfoot{foo \hfill bar}`.

Comment: Thanks @aris, I forgot that no `places` defaults to fill all places, so specifying any place solves it.

Comment: It is multiple times, because `\fancyfoot{...}` means `\fancyfoot[L]`, `\fancyfoot[C]` and `\fancyfoot[R]`, so use `\fancyfoot[L]{...}` or `\fancyfoot[C]{...}`, whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments, specifying a place on `\fancyfoot` like `\fancyfoot[L]` prints the footer only a single time.

Here's the [documentation](https://ctan.crest.fr/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) for `\fancyhead[places]{field}`, `\fancyfoot[places]{field}`, `\fancyhf[places]{field}` (page 4f)

> `places` is a comma-separated list of places where `field` will be placed. There are 12 places defined: Left, Center and Right Headers and Footers, and both can be on Even or Odd pages. Each place therefore has 3 coordinates which are the inital letters of the above description: (1) `E` or `O`, (2) `L`, `C` or `R`, (3) `H` or `F` place is given with 3 letters, like `EOH`. A missing coordinate means: all possibilities, except for `\fancyhead` where `H` is implied and `\fancyfoot` where `F` is implied.

In the original question the code correctly set the footer multiple times on the left, center and right, since no place was set.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[L]{
        \begin{parcolumns}{2}
          \colchunk{foo}
          \colchunk{bar}
        \end{parcolumns}
        }
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\begin{parcolumns}{2}
  \colchunk{
    \blindtext
  }
  \colchunk{
    \blindtext
  }
\end{parcolumns}

\end{document}
```

[image: page with two equal columns containing lorem ipsum placeholder text, in the top right corner the page number "1", at the bottom under the left column the footer "foo" on the left and under the right column the text "bar" on the leff]